# Can I add items to the media library of wordpress without upload?

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress site is hosted on the openshift,and when I edit my site's code and push code to openshift,my file that upload to wordpress will be deleted,so I use some public image storage serves to save my image.But there are some function in wordpress must use the media library...So I want to add the image to the media library by url without upload..What should I do?thanks

p.s:I can edit the code of my wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

Try some plugin like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-external-images/

It's the first i've found, i've never used it before, so look if there's something better.